# Is the same to leave netbeans running on vps or should I run only glassfish?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, environment

I have managed to get my app, up  & running in my vps an over the internet, but I have done using  this from netbeans, is it the same or I should close netbeans, run glassfish from bin files, deploy and start from admin console and have only glassfish running?

Enviroment: glassfish v3, JSF2.0, netbeans 6.8

Thank you very much 
Best regards
Ignacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'standard' way would be to have Glassfish running as a standalone app.

You can still use netbeans to administer it from your machine (by setting up a remote domain GF server in 'services->servers') or you can use the admin console (http://yourhost:4848) or indeed use the asadmin CLI tool.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the delay